# Getting Error: "http code 501:not implement" when using Curl in C++

Tags: curl, libcurl

I used CCProxy to set up a proxy server.
When I use Chrome to connect to my NAS web page through proxy server, the Https connection is work.
But when I run my curl program in c++. my program get a http code 501:not implement.
Does the problem occur in my code or my server settings?
This is a part of my code.

```
handle = curl_easy_init();
if( !handle)
    return false;

curl_socket_t *pSockFD = (curl_socket_t*)(sockFD);

if(( *pSockFD = socket(addrInfo->ai_family, addrInfo->ai_socktype, addrInfo->ai_protocol)) == CURL_SOCKET_BAD)
{
    return false;
}

curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION, CURLRestOpenSocketCallback);
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA, pSockFD);
        
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION, CURLRestSocketOptCallback);
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CURLRestWriteCallback);        
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);

curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, CURLRestHeaderCallback);
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, this);

curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "admin");
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "admin");
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90 );

std::string url = "https://10.10.10.10:3128";
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLVERSION , CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER , 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST , 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL , 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

std::string userPwd = "aaa:bbb";
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, userPwd.c_str());

curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1 );
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```

---

new update 2020/8/19:

I found a strange situation.

When i use curl by command line.

```
curl -x https://10.10.10.10:3128 -k https://99.99.99.99:443/test/one.cgi -d "user=admin&pwd=admin"
```

it's not work.

but when i change proxy url https to http

```
curl -x http://10.10.10.10:3128 -k https://99.99.99.99:443/test/one.cgi -d 
"user=admin&pwd=admin"
```

it's work.

so i change my code to:

```
std::string url = "http://10.10.10.10:3128";
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL , 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
std::string userPwd = "aaa:bbb";
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, userPwd.c_str());
char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] {};
curl_easy_setopt(m_pHttpHandle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
```

I got a new error code: CURLE_RECV_ERROR 
error message: Failure when receiving data from the peer
errbuf: Proxy CONNECT aborted

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: The `http code 501` message is not from libcurl...

Comment: Yes i know , but i don't understand why chrome works.

Comment: So your question is why your libcurl code gets a 501 while chrome doesn't? Then I would say: compare the requests and make sure the libcurl one is a similar as possible to the Chrome one.